# Make an item in a dropdown window "non-focus"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have the selection window of a dropdown menu use a focus tag in css but the actual elements in the dropdown don't use that focus tag? I use the option:checked tag at the moment but that only changes the selected item.
this is the code I have:

```
       <div class="apply_form-entercountry">
            <div>
                <select class="input-entercountry"> /*this is the bit that should use focus*/
                    <option>Country*</option> /*these are the elements without focus*/
                    <option>Afghanistan</option>
                    <option>...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>


.apply_form-entercountry {
  position: relative;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align: left;
  left:37%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.input-entercountry {
  display:block;
  width: 31%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(70, 70, 70);
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.input-entercountry:hover {
  background-color: rgba(150, 204, 148, 0.575);
}

.input-entercountry:focus {
  background-color: rgba(148, 170, 204, 0.397);
  outline: none;
}

.input-entercountry option:checked {
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options of the selection inherit the background color from the selection itself. So by giving them their own background color they will not use the background color of the `<select>` tag.

Just add:

```
.input-entercountry option {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/x93m84t6/